# How to adjust HTML page automatic to fit screen on iOS when first load?

Tags: html, ios, screen

I have a problem about my page on iOS when I RUN the project and click to the menu that I create it's show same like the picture that I upload it's not show fit screen at the first time when I load it's all HTML in this page I try to make it to fit screen when I load at the first not like this please tell me how
 thank so much :D  [Click this link to watch the picture that I upload](http://upic.me/i/uz/screenshot2555-12-18at5.59.16pm.png)

Comment: Could you show us the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you load a page in a `UIWebView`, you can get the size of the external page to resize/modify your webview.

You can edit the code, adding width and/or heigth.

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview
{
  int h = [[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
  int 2 = [[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.width"] floatValue];

  nslog(@"%d %d", h, w);
}
```

Here an article to do this: http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2012/09/objective-c-uiwebview-html-page-size/

hope this helps.